# Don't understand my regex's matches

Tags: regex, perl

I'm currently reading xml balises from a file but I tried to reduce this to this simple example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = '<tag x="20" y="7" x="15" z="14"/>';
if($str =~ /<tag.*(x|y|z)=\"(\d+)\".*(x|y|z)=\"(\d+)\".*(x|y|z)=\"(\d+)\".*\/>/){
    print "$1-$2\n";
    print "$3-$4\n";
    print "$5-$6\n";
}
```

As I understand my regex, the first `x` should match the first group, the first `y` the third group and the second `x` the fifth group.

So I expect as output:

```
x-20
y-7
x-15
```

But I get

```
y-7
x-15
z-14
```

Could someone explain what's happening here?

Comment: Why you are not using xpath?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im This is for training my skills about regular expressions. So only for academic purpose ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `?` to make `*`, `+` quantifiers non-greedy as these are greedy by default (ie. matching any char `.` as much as possible)

```
$str =~ /<tag.*?(x|y|z)=\"(\d+)\".*?(x|y|z)=\"(\d+)\".*?(x|y|z)=\"(\d+)\".*\/>/
```

Comment: Hmm ok that's seems to work :). But why does my regex matches this way? I still don't understand it.

Comment: Greedy means the first `*` jumps all the way to the end of the string, then backtracks until the rest of the expression matches.

Comment: @tripleee yes backtracking is involved to meet matching criteria

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.*` use `\s+`. Becasue you actually want to match multiple space characters. not multiple any characters.

If this is really an assignment you should do it in a more proper way. And regular expression is not proper way for xml thing. As its assignment just write a parser. It easier than you think.

Comment: There can be other attributes that are not x, y and z (I didn't mention it because it was not part of my question). So that's why I used `.*`

Comment: See the problems? thats why you need to use xml parser. Never use regex here. For learning use something else. When you say *there can be other *attributes**. it implies that you are treating them as xml.  But if you could have treated them just a normal text anything can come in middle you should say that. But again ...

Comment: This is for an assigment and I have to do it in plain perl (without any modules or packages). I know there exists XML parsers that can do the job for me.

Comment: Yes but this is an assigment that requires me to write a regex (and that regex will be partially evaluated I suppose) so unfortunately I don't have the choice. But thanks anyway ^^